# Creating a Chart with PHP and MySql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a database with the following table:

```
id    value
-----------
1     yes
2     no
3     no
4     maybe
```

I'm using some simple php to log the choices entered on a poll website. The user selects a radio box and it is entered into the above table. However, I want to make this a little more flexible. I created a simple backend that allowed an admin user to add or delete poll choices. What would I do to show on the frontend the number of votes for each individual choice, when the number of choices is not constant? I know I could do this easily if the poll choices were static but since the backend user will be changing the choices, how could I dynamically display the results?

Comment: There are so many ways to do this... What sort of "display" do you want to achieve?

Comment: I would consider doing this on the front end with JavaScript. There are [many](http://javascript.open-libraries.com/utilities/chart/20-best-javascript-charting-and-plotting-libraries/) libraries available for this.

Comment: I just want to display the number of times a user has selected each poll option. Just a simple number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not really sure what you are asking. Is it [COUNT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html) you're looking for?

Comment: I want to display the number of times each choice has been chosen. Each time a choice is selected, it adds another row into the database with that choice as the value in the "value" column. Hope this makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about the choices or the number of choices, grab all the votes/choices and iterate through them and add them to an array indiscriminately: http://codepad.org/LWPyuTqj

```
$total = array();
$votes = array(1=>'yes',2=>'no',3=>'no',4=>'maybe');
foreach($votes as $vote) {
    if (!isset($total[$vote]))
        $total[$vote] = 1; 
    else
        $total[$vote] += 1;
 }
 print_r($total);
```

Comment: I don't know the number of options the poll will have so I'm not sure how I would add them to an array. It appears from looking at your code snippet that you would need to know the options for it to work.

Comment: no, you don't at all. The options are irrelevant. What this does is count the occurance of any term. Your votes are saved like this: `1: yes` `2: no` etc, my code loops through and counts up the occurances of the words. Check out this sample with a simple paragraph being split into your arrangement: http://codepad.org/Ud7yn8Vz

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend google graph API for this. It is really easy!

http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart.html

Generate the code dynamically, using the first example on the link above. First select the values. This assuming there is a question ID so you can relate to the question. In this case id 1.

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT value,COUNT(*) as num FROM choises WHERE question_id = 1  GROUP BY value');
```

Then with PHP loop through the data

```
$results = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $results[$row['value']] = $num;
}
```

With this you can generate the graph:

```
echo 'data.addRows('.count($results).');';
$i = 0;
foreach ($results as $value => $num){

    echo'
        data.setValue('.$i.', 0, "'.$value.'");
        data.setValue('.$i.', 1, '.$num.');
    ';
    $i++;
}
```